# How come the definition order is not followed when defining static member variables?

Tags: c++, initialization, static-variables

I know about the problem of the order of initialization of static variables from different translation units. However, my problem is within one translation unit and, in fact, within one struct:

```
template <int size>
struct SlidingTile {
    using AllActions = std::array<int, size>;
    using AllMDDeltas = std::array<int, size>;

    int mdDelta(int i) const {
        return mdDeltas_[i];
    }

    static AllActions computeAllActions() {
        std::cout << "computeAllActions" << std::endl;
        AllActions res;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) res[i] = i;
        return res;
    }

    static AllMDDeltas computeAllMDDeltas() {
        std::cout << "Entered computeAllMDDeltas" << std::endl;
        AllActions res;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) res[i] = 10 * allActions_[i];
        std::cout << "Exiting computeAllMDDeltas" << std::endl;
        return res;
    }

private:
    static const AllActions allActions_;
    static const AllMDDeltas mdDeltas_;
};

template <int size>
const typename SlidingTile<size>::AllActions
    SlidingTile<size>::allActions_ = SlidingTile<size>::computeAllActions();

template <int size>
const typename SlidingTile<size>::AllMDDeltas
    SlidingTile<size>::mdDeltas_ = SlidingTile<size>::computeAllMDDeltas();

int main() {
    SlidingTile<3> s;
    std::cout << s.mdDelta(2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Entered computeAllMDDeltas
Exiting computeAllMDDeltas
computeAllActions
```

To my surprise, `computeAllMDDeltas` gets called before `computeAllActions` and so `allActions_` is not initialized when it is used in `computeAllMDDeltas`. Interestingly, `computeAllActions` is not called even when `allActions_` is used in `computeAllMDDeltas`.

Why does this happen and what is the advised way in this situation?

Comment: The bit where `computerAllMDDeltas` uses `allActions_` is clearly not irrelevant - but you have still removed it.  Please give us a [mcve] - this will be a bit of work for you, but as you are the person that has the problem, this seems reasonable.

Comment: Are you *certain* `computeAllMDDeltas` is using `allActions_`?  Can you update the code to give some idea as to the usage.

Comment: Note that the definitions of `allActions_` and `mdDeltas_` are definitions of **templates**, not definitions of objects. `SlidingTile<2, 3>::allActions_` and `SlidingTile<2, 3>::mdDeltas_` do not have explicit definitions.

Comment: I changed the program for a further simplified complete example.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: As usual, entities generated by instantiating templates do not have specific definition points. Your template definitions of static members are not "real" definitions yet. They are just templates. They will "materialize" during instantiation. And no one knows where they will meaterialize and in which order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How come the definition order is not followed when defining static member variables?

Because the standard says that the initialization is unordered:

> [basic.start.init] /2 (N4140 standard draft)
>
> ... Definitions of explicitly specialized class template static data members have ordered initialization. Other
>   **class template static data members (i.e., implicitly or explicitly instantiated specializations) have unordered
>   initialization**. ...

---

> what is the advised way in this situation?

Same as initialization across translation units: *Construct On First Use* idiom:

```
struct SlidingTile {
    // ...
private:
    static const AllActions& allActions() {
        static const AllActions instance = computeAllActions();
        return instance;
    }
    static const AllMDDeltas& mdDeltas() {
        static const AllMDDeltas instance = computeAllMDDeltas();
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that, once the calls to these functions are inlined, there is zero overhead involved in using this technique?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there is a bit of overhead if the program is compiled with multi threading support. The initialization has to be synchronized to prevent a race condition that could happen if multiple threads call the function concurrently.

Comment: Also, did you mean to use `static const` (i.e. did `static` get omitted by mistake?) to prevent re-computing these variables each time the corresponding functions are called?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning whoops! Indeed I did mean to. Returning a reference to a non-static local would have been very wrong.