# Why does this noexcept matters for performance so much while a similar other noexcept does not?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, noexcept

I have a piece of generic code whose performance is important to me, because I was challenged to match its running time of a well-known hand-crafted code written in `C`. Before I began playing with `noexcept`, my code ran in **4.8 seconds**. By putting `noexcept` every place I could think of (I know that this is not a good idea, but I did it for the learning sake), the code sped up to 3.3 seconds. Then I began to revert the changes until I got to even better performance (**3.1 seconds**) and remained with a **single** `noexcept`!

**The question** is: why does this particular `noexcept` help so much? Here it is:

```
static const AllActions& allActions_() noexcept {
    static const AllActions instance = computeAllActions();
    return instance;
}
```

It is interesting that I have another similar function, which is just fine without `noexcept` (i.e. putting `noexcept` there does not improve performance):

```
static const AllMDDeltas& mdDeltas_() {
    static const AllMDDeltas instance = computeAllMDDeltas();
    return instance;
}
```

Both functions are called by my code (which performs recursive depth-first search) a lot of times, so that the second function is as important for overall performance as the first one.

**P.S.** Here is the surrounding code for more context (the quoted functions and the functions that they call are at the end of the listing):

```
/// The sliding-tile puzzle domain.
/// \tparam nRows Number of rows on the board.
/// \tparam nRows Number of columns on the board.
template <int nRows, int nColumns>
struct SlidingTile : core::sb::DomainBase {
    /// The type representing the cost of actions in the domain. Every
    /// domain must provide this name.
    using CostType = int;

    using SNeighbor =
        core::sb::StateNeighbor<SlidingTile>; ///< State neighbor type.
    using ANeighbor =
        core::sb::ActionNeighbor<SlidingTile>; ///< Action neighbor type.

    /// The type for representing an action. The position of the tile being moved.
    using Action = int;

    /// Number of positions.
    static constexpr int size_ = nRows * nColumns;

    /// The type for the vector of actions for a given position of the blank.
    using BlankActions = std::vector<ANeighbor>;

    /// The type for all the actions in the domain.
    using AllActions = std::array<BlankActions, size_>;

    /// The type for two-dimension array of Manhattan distance heuristic deltas
    /// for a given tile. The indexes are from and to of an action.
    using TileMDDeltas = std::array<std::array<int, size_>, size_>;

    /// The type for all Manhattan distance heuristic deltas.
    using AllMDDeltas = std::array<TileMDDeltas, size_>;

    /// The type for raw state representation.
    using Board = std::array<int, size_>;

    /// Initializes the ordered state.
    SlidingTile() {
        int i = -1;
        for (auto &el : tiles_) el = ++i;
    }

    /// Initializes the state from a string, e.g. "[1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5]" or "1 4 2
    /// 4 0 5" for 3x2 board.
    /// \param s The string.
    SlidingTile(const std::string &s) {
        int i = -1;
        for (auto el : core::util::split(s, {' ', ',', '[', ']'})) {
            tiles_[++i] = std::stoi(el);
            if (tiles_[i] == 0) blank_ = i;
        }
    }

    /// The default copy constructor.
    SlidingTile(const SlidingTile &) = default;

    /// The default assignment operator.
    /// \return Reference to the assigned state.
    SlidingTile &operator=(const SlidingTile &) = default;

    /// Returns the array of tiles at each position.
    /// \return The raw representation of the state, which is the array of tiles
    /// at each position..
    const Board &getTiles() const { return tiles_; }

    /// Applies an action to the state.
    /// \param a The action to be applied, i.e. the next position of the blank
    /// on the board.
    /// \return The state after the action.
    SlidingTile &apply(Action a) {
        tiles_[blank_] = tiles_[a];
        blank_ = a;
        return *this;
    }

    /// Returns the reverse of the given action in this state.
    /// \param a The action whose reverse is to be returned.
    /// \return The reverse of the given action.
    Action reverseAction(Action a) const {
        (void)a;
        return blank_;
    }

    /// Computes the state neighbors of the state.
    /// \return Vector of state neighbors of the state.
    std::vector<SNeighbor> stateSuccessors() const {
        std::vector<SNeighbor> res;
        for (auto a : actionSuccessors()) {
            auto n = SlidingTile{*this}.apply(a.action());
            res.push_back(std::move(n));
        }
        return res;
    }

    /// Computes the action neighbors of the state.
    /// \return Vector of action neighbors of the state.
    const std::vector<ANeighbor> &actionSuccessors() const {
        return allActions_()[blank_];
    }

    /// The change in the Manhattan distance heuristic to the goal state with
    /// ordered tiles and the blank at position 0 due to applying the given action.
    /// \param a The given action.
    /// \return The change in the Manhattan distance heuristic to the goal state
    /// with ordered pancake due to applying the given action.
    int mdDelta(Action a) const {
        return mdDeltas_()[tiles_[a]][a][blank_];
    }

    /// Computes the Manhattan distance heuristic to the goal state with
    /// ordered tiles and the blank at position 0.
    /// \return The Manhattan distance heuristic to the goal state with
    /// ordered tiles and the blank at position 0.
    int mdHeuristic() const {
        int res = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size_; ++pos)
            if (pos != blank_)
                res += rowDist(pos, tiles_[pos]) + colDist(pos, tiles_[pos]);
        return res;
    }

    /// Computes the hash-code of the state.
    /// \return The hash-code of the state.
    std::size_t hash() const {
        boost::hash<Board> v_hash;
        return v_hash(tiles_);
    }

    /// Dumps the state to the given stream.
    /// \tparam The stream type.
    /// \param o The stream.
    /// \return The modified stream.
    template <class Stream> Stream &dump(Stream &o) const {
        return o << tiles_;
    }

    /// Randomly shuffles the tiles.
    void shuffle() {
        auto old = tiles_;
        while (old == tiles_)
            std::random_shuffle(tiles_.begin(), tiles_.end());
    }

    /// The equality operator.
    /// \param rhs The right-hand side of the operator.
    /// \return \c true if the two states compare equal and \c false
    /// otherwise.
    bool operator==(const SlidingTile &rhs) const {
        if (blank_ != rhs.blank_) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size_; ++i)
            if (i != blank_ && tiles_[i] != rhs.tiles_[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }

    /// Returns a random state.
    /// \return A random state.
    static SlidingTile random() {
        SlidingTile res{};
        res.shuffle();
        return res;
    }

private:
    /// Tile at each position. This does not include the position of the blank,
    /// which is stored separately.
    std::array<int, size_> tiles_;

    /// Blank position.
    int blank_{};

    /// Computes the row number corresponding to the given position.
    /// \return The row number corresponding to the given position.
    static int row(int pos) { return pos / nColumns; }

    /// The difference between the row numbers corresponding to the two given
    /// positions.
    /// \return The difference between the row numbers corresponding to the two
    /// given positions.
    static int rowDiff(int pos1, int pos2) { return row(pos1) - row(pos2); }

    /// The distance between the row numbers corresponding to the two given
    /// positions.
    /// \return The distance between the row numbers corresponding to the two
    /// given positions.
    static int rowDist(int pos1, int pos2) {
        return std::abs(rowDiff(pos1, pos2));
    }

    /// Computes the column number corresponding to the given position.
    /// \return The column number corresponding to the given position.
    static int col(int pos) { return pos % nColumns; }

    /// The difference between the column numbers corresponding to the two given
    /// positions.
    /// \return The difference between the column numbers corresponding to the
    /// two given positions.
    static int colDiff(int pos1, int pos2) { return col(pos1) - col(pos2); }

    /// The distance between the column numbers corresponding to the two given
    /// positions.
    /// \return The distance between the column numbers corresponding to the
    /// two given positions.
    static int colDist(int pos1, int pos2) {
        return std::abs(colDiff(pos1, pos2));
    }

    /// Computes the actions available for each position of the blank.
    static AllActions computeAllActions() {
        AllActions res;
        for (int blank = 0; blank < size_; ++blank) {
            // the order is compatible with the code of Richard Korf.
            if (blank > nColumns - 1)
                res[blank].push_back(Action{blank - nColumns});
            if (blank % nColumns > 0)
                res[blank].push_back(Action{blank - 1});
            if (blank % nColumns < nColumns - 1)
                res[blank].push_back(Action{blank + 1});
            if (blank < size_ - nColumns)
                res[blank].push_back(Action{blank + nColumns});
        }
        return res;
    }

    /// Computes the heuristic updates for all the possible moves.
    /// \return The heuristic updates for all the possible moves.
    static AllMDDeltas computeAllMDDeltas() {
        AllMDDeltas res;
        for (int tile = 1; tile < size_; ++tile) {
            for (int blank = 0; blank < size_; ++blank) {
                for (const ANeighbor &a: allActions_()[blank]) {
                    int from = a.action(), to = blank;
                    res[tile][from][to] =
                        (rowDist(tile, to) - rowDist(tile, from)) +
                        (colDist(tile, to) - colDist(tile, from));
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    /// Returns all the actions.
    /// \note See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42208278/2725810
    static const AllActions& allActions_() noexcept {
        static const AllActions instance = computeAllActions();
        return instance;
    }

    /// Returns all the updates of the MD heuristic.
    static const AllMDDeltas& mdDeltas_() {
        static const AllMDDeltas instance = computeAllMDDeltas();
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe the compiler can deduce that `computeAllMDDeltas` will not throw, so adding `noexcept` doesn't change anything. But for `computeAllActions` the compiler is not sure, so adding it to `allActions_` will help the compiler with its optimizations. The only way to *really* knows what's happening and what the difference is, is to compare the generated code using a disassembler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Still, what is so special about `allActions_`? Out of dozens of functions, making this one function `noexcept` improved the overall performance by a staggering 54%!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `computeAllMDDeltas`, the function `computeAllActions` contains some calls to `push_back`, which may perform some memory allocations. This may throw if there is an exception from the underlying allocator, for example if you run out of memory. That is something which the compiler cannot optimize away, since it depends on runtime parameters.

Adding `noexcept` tells the compiler that these errors can not occur, which allows him to omit the code for exception handling.

Comment: To check this hypothesis, I moved `noexcept` to `computeAllActions`. The performance degraded to 3.5 seconds. Making both functions (i.e.  `computeAllActions` and `allActions_`) `noexcept` does not make things better... So, some more explanation seems to be needed...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this discussion on exception overhead : [Are Exceptions in C++ really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835817/are-exceptions-in-c-really-slow)

You can get an easy understanding why your code is faster with noexcept, since the compiler does not need to create the list of handlers for each call to push_back that you make. Your function computeAllActions contains the majority of your calls to a throwable function which is why it gets the most out of the optimization.

Comment: To check this hypothesis, I moved `noexcept` to `computeAllActions`. The performance degraded to 3.5 seconds. Making both functions (i.e.  `computeAllActions` and `allActions_`) `noexcept` does not make things better... So, some more explanation seems to be needed...

Comment: A working project might help shed some light on this, is there any possibilities to get a working case of your code?

Comment: You can get it here: https://github.com/mgoldenbe/search-framework, but some work will be required to run it as explained here: http://homedir.jct.ac.il/~mgoldenb/documentation/html/index.html#s-install.